# How to get variable value bound in function called by a variable

Tags: javascript

```
var hello = function myFunction(){
   a = 20;
};

myFunction();
alert(a);
```

Trying to **get alert as 20**.
Can we do it?

Comment: `var hello = function myFunction() { var a = 20; alert(a); } myFunction();`

Answer (score 0):

You can give the alert inside the function itself.

```
var hello = function myFunction()
   {
   a = 20;
   alert(a);
   }
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Say like bellow

```
var myFunction = function ()
   {
   a = 20;
   }
myFunction();
alert(a);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/86/)

Answer (score 0):

You have three choices:

1. Have the function *return* the value you want to alert:

   ```
   var hello = function myFunction()
      {
      var a = 20;
      return a;
      }
   alert(myFunction());  // But see note below
   ```
2. `alert` from *within* the function:

   ```
   var hello = function myFunction()
      {
      va a = 20;
      alert(a);
      }
   myFunction(); // But see note below
   ```
3. Have `myFunction` set a variable it closes over:

   ```
   var a;
   var hello = function myFunction()
      {
      a = 20;
      }
   myFunction(); // But see note below
   alert(a);
   ```

Note that I've added `var` to each of those to declare `a`, since otherwise you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

---

Side note: On a browser that correctly implements function expressions, your code will fail, because the identifier `myFunction` isn't in scope where you're using it. (The function name on a function *expression* isn't added to the scope where the expression is.) Either use `hello` instead, or change your function expression to a declaration, e.g. (for the first example):

```
function myFunction()
   {
   var a = 20;
   return a;
   }
alert(myFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need declare the `a` variable in the **`same scope` or `global scope`**;

```
var a;

function myFunction(){
   a = 20;
};

myFunction();
alert(a); // prints 20
```

See the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tmmvuqch/). You must read about `declaring variables in Javascript`.